# Why do I need to return my list from my function for it to change outside the function?

Tags: python

I'm coding a table sorting method called `TriShaker`. I have this procedure that changes the table.

In other functions, `t` would be modified without returning it, but in this one I have to for some reason otherwise it won't work. Hopefully you will understand better with the code :

```
def TriCreation(t, n):
    v = [int()] * n
    for i in range(n):
        v[i] = MinRemplace(t,n)
    
    t = v
    return(t)

t = [5,987,12,689,8,3,1,4,865,7,3,2,5,8,99,12,545,21]  
print(t)

t = TriCreation(t, len(t))
print(t)
```

`v` is the organized table so `t = v`

Comment: Before we go further... a few style tips for Python. 1) start function names with lower case characters - convention is to reserve capitalized names for classes. 2) no need for the parenthesis on the return as `return` is a keyword like `try` or `except` not a function. 3) `int()` is very strange to see, I guess it returns 0, but that's odd.

Comment: It seems liek you didn't finish to write the question...

Comment: I think your issue is that you are trying to modify `t` inplace, but you are making a new object when you do `v=[int()]*n` - so when you modify v it makes no changes to `t`

Comment: Or rather, the issue is that when you do `t=v` that is not updating what the name `t` is pointing to outside the local scope.

Comment: Probably good to read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `t=v` within `TriCreation()` means that `t` no longer points to the same list anymore. It now points to the same list as `v`. So when you do `return t`, that's actually just returning `v` now essentially. You could skip `t=v` and just do `return v` for a functionally identical result.

If you modified `t` rather than creating the new list `v`, then you could just call `TriCreation(t,len(t))` without assigning the result to `t`. If you wanted to keep the original `t` list, you could assign to a different variable, like `new_t=TriCreation(t,len(t))`.